# Навигация в UWP приложениях

Tags: c#, uwp

Допустим, у меня есть NavigationView с некоторым числом item-ов и Frame
Как мне сделать так, чтобы менялось отображение только в Frame?
В инете нашёл только Frame.Navigate() , но он просто "переносит" на новое окно, в результате чего пропадает NavigationView

## Дополнение

Вот xaml-код MainPage:

```
<Page
x:Name="mainPage"
x:Class="LangLayoutAssist.Pages.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"

Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlAcrylicWindowBrush}">

<Grid>
    <NavigationView x:Name="menu" IsSettingsVisible="False" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" ItemInvoked="NavigationView_ItemInvoked">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItemHeader>Language Layout Assistant</NavigationViewItemHeader>
            <NavigationViewItem Tag="Home" Icon="Home">Главная страница</NavigationViewItem>
            <NavigationViewItem Tag="Settings" Icon="Setting">Настройки</NavigationViewItem>
            <NavigationViewItem Tag="Reference" Icon="Help">Справка</NavigationViewItem>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    </NavigationView>
    <Frame x:Name="frame">

    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

Вот реализация события ItemInvoked:

```
private void NavigationView_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.InvokedItemContainer.Tag.ToString())
        {
            case "Home":
                frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPageBP));
                break;
            case "Settings":
                frame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsBP));
                break;
            case "Reference":
                frame.Navigate(typeof(ReferenceBP));
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Page not found");
        }
    }
```

Остальные страницы пустые, ничего в них не менял. Если код костыльный (меня смущает использование в switch-case литералов), то извините, я не знаю, как такое принято делать, учусь.

Comment: У какой `Frame` вызываете `Navigate`? Этот пример пробовали: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/05/06/using-the-navigationview-in-your-uwp-applications/ ?

Comment: Это первая страница, которую я посмотрел по этой теме.
У меня есть в коде xaml строчка <Frame x:Name="frame"></Frame>
Вот этот frame я и вызываю, но перерисовывается всё окно
Может быть я не тот элемент передаю в frame.Navigate(), потому что я передаю туда Blank Page

Comment: Хорошо, добавьте в текст вопроса пример для воспроизведения проблемы

Comment: Добавил код, надеюсь, что он не полное Г

Comment: По ссылке я вижу, что `Frame` *внутри* `NavigationView`, у вас же она *рядом*

Comment: Блин, как же я щас облажался....
Спасибо за помощь, теперь работает

Comment: Отлично, оформите то что сделали ответом!

Comment: "Для того, чтобы отметить ответ принятым, нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом."
Но этой галки нет

Comment: Ну так напишите ответ сначала, поле ввода "Ваш ответ" внизу, потом уже и примите его

Comment: окей, прошу прощения за то, что туплю

Answer (score 1):

`Frame` необходимо поместить внутрь `NavigationView`